# Servlet filter is called multiple times

Tags: java, servlets, tiles

I have a task to do some action (Pop up) on the web site if user visits site second time (any page). I decided to implement it with Servlet Filter + cookie. But I ran into the problem - filter calls multiple times, I think it related to using of tiles. 
Could you help me to fix it up? Or maybe somebody know the best practices for implementing this task.

Filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Do filter..............");

    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String valueFromCookie = getCookieValue(request.getCookies(), EMAIL_POPUP_COOKIE);

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(EMAIL_POPUP_COOKIE, "");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setComment("Email Pop up cookie");
    cookie.setMaxAge(COOKIE_LIFE_TIME);

    if (valueFromCookie == null){
        String valueToCookie = URLEncoder.encode(FIRST_VISIT, "UTF-8");
        cookie.setValue(valueToCookie);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    } else {
        if (valueFromCookie.equals(FIRST_VISIT)){
            String valueToCookie = URLEncoder.encode(NOT_SHOW, "UTF-8");
            cookie.setValue(valueToCookie);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            System.out.println("STOP!=======================>");
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
}
```

web.xml part:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EmailPopUp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: In order to help us help you, you might want to provide some more information, e.g. how you handle that cookie etc. Btw, what about just setting some flag in the request attributes and when rendering the page you read it once? It would then almost not matter whether the filter is called multiple times or not.

Comment: Dont use filters, filters are for doing some work on the requests before your servlet is executed and on the response objects before sending the response to the client, use an `HttpSessionListener` instead.

Comment: But Session listener will be called only one time. It doesn't work on the all another pages .

Comment: If your client sends multiple requests in parallel, it may happen that the cookie of the first request isn't set before the second request arrives. So this is not (theoretically) possible. I think your best bet is to store a flag in the server's session as @Thomas suggested. You can always set a cookie for later.

Comment: Do note that right now you have your filter configured to be executed for EVERYTHING, so also images, stylesheets, javascript files, etc. You might want to narrow that url-pattern down a bit more, like adding a file extension (*.jsp for example).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using JSF, it's important to be aware that different JSF components perform different combinations GET and POST requests when executed.

For instance:

- `<h:commandLink >` performs both, a GET and a POST request when clicked
- `<h:link >`        performs only a GET request when clicked

If you are using a filter and you click a `<h:commandLink >` you will notice that the filter is called twice.
Additionally, remember that any type of request (ajax, resource, etc.) that matches the url pattern defined in web.xml, will pass through the filter so it will be called multiple times.

You can use browser developer tools to check which types and how many requests are being performed.